# How do I change a db model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to ruby on rails.

I have already created all the models and the schema, my database has its fields filled too.

However, when I want to change an association between tables or to add another field to a table, what type of commands and in what order should I run?

**for example:**

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

should I generate model of tables first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a new feature in your application you need to ask yourself 'does this feature need a table?'.

Let's take a simple example: blog post app

A blog post app usually has a **posts** table and a **author** table.

Now lets say that you want to have comments on your blog posts. The first question to ask is do you need a table for comments where you will be saving each comment associated with each post. The answer is yes you do need a comments table since you will be persisting the data to your database.

command to create a new comments table:

`rails generate migration create_comments`

in `db/migration/create_comments.rb` you'll see

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
      create_table :comments do |t|
      end
    end
end
```

Then you can safely add to this table any column you need.

Now migrate with `rake db:migrate`

Your schema is now updated with the new comments table.
Once you have your db set up, the next thing you need to do it create a comment model.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

You'll have to make the appropriate **associations**; this is a crucial part-- you want to set up your architecture in a way that will make it easy for all the different parts of your application to communicate with each other. Take a look at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on ActiveRecord Associations.

After this part you'll need to set up your routes in `config/routes.rb` and create a comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
    end
end
```

Set up your routes so that when someone comments on a post the POST request will be sent to the create action in your comments controller. Take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) for more info.